# Saving the "View" of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Imagine an application where some data is displayed in a JTable. The application developer have set a default layout for the JTable, that the user might not be happy with. If the user edit the table view, by swaping some columns, resizing others, etc, is there a function to get the view parameters hidden in the doc, so that I can get them and save them for reuse?

Comment: as already mentioned: nothing out of the box, you have to do it yourself. For ideas, have a look at how it is done [XProperties in SwingX/Appframework](http://java.net/projects/jdnc-incubator/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/kleopatra/java/org/jdesktop/appframework/swingx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no really easy way. You can get and set column widths with get/setWidth methods on the TableColumn object. And you can manipulate the order using this code :

```
int columnIndex = jtable.convertColumnIndexToView(jtable.getColumn("colname").getModelIndex());
    jtable.getColumnModel().moveColumn(columnIndex, e.getValue());
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this. You just have to get the width and order, save it, and then reset it at a later point (usually when you open the application again).